# How to remove Linux.MulDrop.14?

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, malware

My son's Raspberry PI is infected with Linux.MulDrop.14. Can anyone post steps to remove it? I am working on it but am not quite there yet.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , How did you know that you rpi is infected?

Answer (score 2):

The only safe way is to wipe out the PI's SD card and reinstall the system. Even if you managed to stop and remove all the malware-installed services, it might have left behind some backdoor.

I recently posted [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370638/how-to-secure-raspberry-pie-controlled-over-ssh-against-the-linux-muldrop-14-mal/371038#371038) which explains how to defend yourself from the malware and prevent it to infect again your Raspberry PI.

Comment: I think I have an infected Pi, but I can still SSH into it probably because of shared SSH keys. In this case, do you know how I can remove it?

Comment: Some helpful information https://www.dfn-cert.de/dokumente/workshop/2019/Folien_Gerling.pdf